# React using setState functional updates in useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) you don't need to include the setState functions in the useCallback dependency array. Is it okay to use functional updates without including either the state or the setState function in the dependency array? If so, why?

Example code:

```js
const foo = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
  const inc = useCallback(() => setCount(prev => prev + 1), []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button onClick={inc}>Inc</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Naturally, you would write that as follows: `useCallback(() => setCount(count + 1), [count]);`.

Answer (score 0):

The example code is the better way to go.  In your example, the `useCallback()` function is being updated every time the count changes.  This means, the client's resources are being used to redefine the `useCallback()` function every time the count is updated.

But really, you only need to define the `useCallback()` one time, after the component's first render; nothing about how the function operates is changing.  And this is what the example code achieves.  When you pass a function to `setCount()`, you get as a parameter the reference to the existing state (the `prev` parameter in this example, though you can call it whatever you wish).  This means you don't need to redefine the `useCallback()` every time the `count` state changes because the reference to `count` (via `prev`) is always the same.  Thus, you optimize your code by defining the `useCallback()` function just the one time on the first render (because of the empty dependency array).

Your way would work technically, but it would also defeat the purpose of using `useCallback()` because you redefine the function on each update of `count`, which is essentially what `useCallback()` is designed to avoid.